# KeyboardAvoidingView doesn't work on selecting emojis from the keyboard

Tags: android, ios, react-native, keyboard

The `KeyboardAvoidingView` covers the `TextInput` UI while selecting emojis from the virtual keyboard.

Here is a sample code, `KeyboardAvoidingView` in this case works fine on entering the text from the virtual keyboard. however, on switching to the emoji picker in the virtual keyboard the automatically adjusted `padding | height` has no effect and the `TextInput` gets covered under the virtual keyboard.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, KeyboardAvoidingView, TextInput, StyleSheet, Text,,TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard } from 'react-native';

const KeyboardAvoidingComponent = () => {
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
      style={styles.container}
    >
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
        <View style={styles.inner}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>Keyboard Avoiding View</Text>
          ...
          <FlatList 
          ...
          <TextInput placeholder="Username" style={styles.textInput} />
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  inner: {
    padding: 24,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "space-around"
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 36,
    marginBottom: 50
  },
  textInput: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "#000000",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 36
  },
});

export default KeyboardAvoidingComponent;
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug in the RN library itself. In our project, I just patched the library with the changes you can also find in the PR I submitted to RN.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/34749

This ensures that the height is calculated correctly when switching keyboards.

Comment: This functional seems broken in RN 0.70.5 again. Here is my issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35764

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current solution for this problem:

- on Android I set `android.softwareKeyboardLayoutMode: "pan"` in Expo app.json (docs: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#softwarekeyboardlayoutmode) and I dont use any keyboard-avoid solution at all. In my experience Android handles text Input just fine out of the box with this config.
- on ios I use `KeyboardAvoidingView` with `behavior: "padding"`, which works fine for all keyboards (including Emoji). Please beware of `behavior: "height"` - it is bugged at the moment in RN 0.7.5 (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35764)

Here is my code:

```js
React.createElement(Platform.OS === 'ios' ? KeyboardAvoidingView : View, {
    style: container,
    behavior: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? "padding" : null,
},
... // children
)
```

Please also take a look at a great article explaining modern ways of keyboard avoiding for IOS, Android in different cases https://www.netguru.com/blog/avoid-keyboard-react-native